# which certificate/identifiers/profilers should be used for python script to be distributed as a pyinstaller build/bundle outside the app store?

Tags: macos, applescript, python, certificate, code-signing

My program works as follows

In a while loop, it checks for the active window change - AppKit library used

```
from AppKit import NSWorkspace

active_window = (NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().activeApplication()['NSApplicationName'])
```

if the active window changes to from some other window to google chrome, I need get the url from the chrome's current tab using apple script as :

```
url="""tell application "System Events"
        tell application "Google Chrome" to get the URL of the active tab of window 1 as string
        end tell"""
```

This script is running fine, I can able to get the current window name and also url

I need to know which kind of identifier, provisioning profile, certificate should be used for the same

Im confused of choosing the certificate

I don't have any idea if I need to have a  provisioning profile

Im not going to place this app in mac app store, I just wanted to use this app to support another electron application

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I had found out how to code sign using certificate identity, how to notarize the app bundle and all but don't know what certificate to use.

Comment: Do you qualify for a free developer account with Apple?

Answer (score 0):

Outside the App Store you can use any ad-hoc or self signed certificate, but I recommend using an official developer account Developer ID for maxim ease of use.

Letting Apple [notarize your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution) by signing your developer ID certificate, helps people trust your app.

Notarization is free for everyone except the submitter of the app. To notarize a specific item, You have to posess a current developer signing certificates. These can be obtained from an annual paid or free developer account (if you qualify for a free account).

The certificate type differs if you sign an installer vs signing an application.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues#3087721

> When code signing items like Mach-O files, disk images, bundles, apps, command line tools, photos, and so on, sign with a Developer ID Application certificate. Sign installer packages with a Developer ID Installer certificate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111397/discussion-between-chitharthan-and-bmike).

Comment: @bmike It's not clear: is Notarization "free", or is it part of the $99 paid-for dev subscription?

Comment: You are awesome @benwiggy my statement looks really wrong - let me edit it. Many people get free developer accounts. Then it’s free for all. Some have to pay annually, then it’s not free to them - but still free for everyone else. At worst one person has to pay for a year of basically unlimited notarization requests.